# Error: all arrays must be same length. But they ARE the same length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am doing some work about sentiment analysis, here I have three arrays:the content of the sentences, the sentiment score and the key words.

I want to display them as a dataframe by pandas, but I got :
**"ValueError: arrays must all be same length"**

Here are some of my codes:

```
 print(len(text_sentences),len(score_list),len(keyinfo_list))

    df = pd.DataFrame(text_sentences,score_list,keyinfo_list)

    print(df)
```

Here are the results:

```
182 182 182
```

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-cfb70aca07d1> in <module>()
     21 print(len(text_sentences),len(score_list),len(keyinfo_list))
     22 
---> 23 df = pd.DataFrame(text_sentences,score_list,keyinfo_list)
     24 
     25 print(df)

E:\learningsoft\anadonda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    328                 else:
    329                     mgr = self._init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype,
--> 330                                              copy=copy)
    331             else:
    332                 mgr = self._init_dict({}, index, columns, dtype=dtype)

E:\learningsoft\anadonda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _init_ndarray(self, values, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    472                     raise_with_traceback(e)
    473 
--> 474         index, columns = _get_axes(*values.shape)
    475         values = values.T
    476 

E:\learningsoft\anadonda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _get_axes(N, K, index, columns)
    439                 columns = _default_index(K)
    440             else:
--> 441                 columns = _ensure_index(columns)
    442             return index, columns
    443 

E:\learningsoft\anadonda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in _ensure_index(index_like, copy)
   4015         if len(converted) > 0 and all_arrays:
   4016             from .multi import MultiIndex
-> 4017             return MultiIndex.from_arrays(converted)
   4018         else:
   4019             index_like = converted

E:\learningsoft\anadonda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py in from_arrays(cls, arrays, sortorder, names)
   1094         for i in range(1, len(arrays)):
   1095             if len(arrays[i]) != len(arrays[i - 1]):
-> 1096                 raise ValueError('all arrays must be same length')
   1097 
   1098         from pandas.core.categorical import _factorize_from_iterables

ValueError: all arrays must be same length
```

You can see **all my three arrays contain 182 elements,** so I don't understand why it said "all arrays must be same length".

Comment: Check if there are duplicates in indices column

Answer (score 3):

You're passing the wrong data into [`pandas.DataFrame`'s initializer](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame).
The way you're using it, you're essentially running:

```
pandas.DataFrame(data=text_sentences, index=score_list, columns=keyinfo_list)
```

This isn't what you want. You probably want to do something like this instead:

```
pd.DataFrame(data={
    'sentences': text_sentences,
    'scores': score_list,
    'keyinfo': keyinfo_list
})
```